# wss.clients undefined - node.js

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner of node.js. Recently, I'm trying to use node.js to build a WebSocket server.
Here is my code(simplified) and question.

```
const https = require('https');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 3000});
......

wss.on('connection',wss => {
  console.log("Connected.");
  console.log("wss.clients"); //undefined
});

......
```

I wanna print all clients in the console, but the console printed "undefined". I searched on the web and connot find a way to solve it.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. Also take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, according to ['ws' npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws), you should use `WebSocketServer`:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.WebSocketServer({port: 3000});
```

secondly, you should use different name for the callback parameter:

```
wss.on('connection', socket => {
});
```

finally:

```
// console.log("wss.clients");
console.log(wss.clients);
```